# get specific text from .txt file in php

Tags: php, string, text

I am having a log file like this :

```
2013-04-08-03-17-52: Cleaning Up all data for restart operation
2013-04-08-03-18-02: Creating new instance of app before closing
2013-04-08-03-18-03: New instance created and running
2013-04-08-03-18-03: Application started
```

Currently, i am loading full log file every second to show it to the user using jquery ajax, As this being soo inefficient i am trying to figure out some way to load only the updated lines from log file.

Is their any way to get lines only after a particular time stamp `2013-04-08-03-18-03` 
, For this i will be managing a variable with last timestamp and will be updating it every time i get new lines.

I am kind of New to Php and know only the basics of reading and writing files.

Comment: why not just load tail entries ?

Comment: @Baba can you please explain .. i don't know how that work's

Comment: See code below ... introduce maximum lines also ability to move file pointer to the start position of the last retrial with date validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the file modification time first to see whether or not you need to reload the log file. You can use the [`filemtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)-function for that.

Furthermore, you can use the [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)-function using an offset to read the file from a certain point.

**Edit**: So, how does it work?

Suppose you have stored the last modification time in a session variable `$_SESSION['log_lastmod']` and the most recent offset in `$_SESSION['log_offset']`.

```
session_start();

// First, check if the variables exist. If not, create them so that the entire log is read.
if (!isset($_SESSION['log_lastmod']) && !isset($_SESSION['log_offset'])) {
    $_SESSION['log_lastmod'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['log_offset'] = 0;
}

if (filemtime('log.txt') > $_SESSION['log_lastmod']) {
    // read file from offset
    $newcontent = file_get_contents('log.txt', NULL, NULL, $_SESSION['log_offset']);
    // set new offset (add newly read characters to last offset)
    $_SESSION['log_offset'] += strlen($newcontent);
    // set new lastmod-time
    $_SESSION['log_lastmod'] = filemtime('log.txt');

    // manipulate $newcontent here to what you want it to show
} else {
    // put whatever should be returned to the client if there are no updates here
}
```

Comment: how can i set the offset while i do not know about the starting position of new lines

Comment: Record the size of the previously accessed file using the [`filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)-function to get the offset. Once read, save the new filesize.

Comment: That seems good,  can you please explain with some code...I am kind of new to php

Comment: `;)`   .. Worked...!  Thanks for the Code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
session_start();
if (! isset($_SESSION['log'])) {
    $log = new stdClass();
    $log->timestamp = "2013-04-08-03-18-03";
    $log->position = 0;
    $log->max = 2;
    $_SESSION['log'] = &$log;
} else {
    $log = &$_SESSION['log'];
}

$format = "Y-m-d-:g:i:s";
$filename = "log.txt";

// Get last date
$dateLast = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $log->timestamp);

$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
fseek($fp, $log->position); // prevent loading all file to memory

$output = array();
$i = 0;
while ( $i < $log->max && ! feof($fp) ) {
    $content = fgets($fp);

    // Check if date is current
    if (DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $log->timestamp) < $dateLast)
        continue;

    $log->position = ftell($fp); // save current position
    $log->timestamp = strstr($content, ":", true); // save curren time;
    $output[] = $content;
    $i ++;
}

fclose($fp);
echo json_encode($output); // send to ajax
```

Comment: I tried your code.. but doesn't seem to return the new lines..instead it is returning only two random lines....IDK but `$log->timestamp = strstr($content, ":", true);` in this.. what if i have multiple `:` in text after timestamp ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $lines = file(/*Insert logfile path here*/);
    if(isset($_SESSION["last_date_stamp"])){
        $new_lines = array();
        foreach($lines as $line){
            // If the date stamp is newer than the session variable, add it to $new_lines
        }
        $returnLines = array_reverse($newLines); // the reverse is to put the lines in the right order
    } else {
        $returnLines = $lines;
    }
    $_SESSION['last_date_stamp'] = /* Insert the most recent date stamp here */;
    // return the $returnLines variable
?>
```

What this does is reads a file line by line and, if a session variable already exists, add all of the lines where the date stamp is newer than the one in the session variable to a return variable `$returnLines`, if no session variable exists it will put all of the lines in the file in `$returnLines`.

After this, it create.updates the session variable for use the next time the code is executed. Finally it returns the log file data by using the `$returnLines` variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought he problem was sending the file back to jQuery rather than just the new lines